# How to run BTEQ Script using two Tables each table should load on seperate Query

Tags: bash, unix, teradata

I am trying to create a **BTEQ script**, where it should give a mail in Table format like TableName, Curent_Date_Loaded and No.of Records Loaded.

I have **two tables** and I looking for a result like when the first BTEQ query is executed and retrieves no values(rows) it should run to the Next Query but the main thing is I want only the **table which not retrieves any values** should run on the second query.
If the table doesn't retrieves any values(rows) even in second query, have to throw a message like "**Table was not Loaded Today**" using Send mail in Scripting

**tablecollist.txt** contains

ABC|Load_Date

DEF|Load_Date

In my case both the tables are loading on both the query..Where do the fix is needed.

```
#! /bin/sh
set -vx

optfile="/home/scripts/opt.txt"
[[ -f $optfile ]] &&  rm $optfile

dbcred="******,******"

touch $optfile

for i in `cat tablecollist.txt`
do
tbl=`echo $i|awk -F '|' '{print $1}'`
col=`echo $i|awk -F '|' '{print $2}'`
done

/usr/bin/bteq << EOF

.LOGON abc${hostsuffix}.xyz.yzx.com/$dbcred;

.SET SEPARATOR '|'
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF;
.SET NULL AS ''

.EXPORT REPORT FILE=$optfile
.SET QUIET ON;

DATABASE par_yzx_db;

sel '$tbl' as tablename, cast($col as date) as Load_Date,count(*)
from $tbl where $col=cast(current_date as date format 'dd-mm-yyyy')
group by cast ($col as date);

.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT =0 THEN .GOTO DoQuery2;

.LABEL DoQuery2;

sel '$tbl' as tablename, cast($col as date) as load_date, count(*) from
$tbl where cast($col as date) = current_date-1 group by load_date;

GOTO End;
.LABEL End;

IF ERRORCODE > 0 THEN .QUIT 10;
.LOGOFF;
.EXIT
EOF
done

cdate=`date +'%F'`
sed -i -e '/tablename/d' $optfile


if [[ -s $optfile ]] ; then
SUBJECT=`echo "Important Tables yzx status: $cdate"`
/usr/bin/awk  -F"|" -v SUBJECT="Subject: ${SUBJECT}" 'BEGIN {
 print "From: abc@xyz.com"
 print "To: 123@xyz.com"
 print "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 print "Content-Type: text/html"
 print SUBJECT
 print "<html><body><table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 style=font-family:Calibri;>"
 print "<tr>"
 print "<td>Table_Name</td>";
 print "<td>Load Date</td>";
 print "<td>Count</td>";
 print "</tr>"
} {
 print "<tr>"
 print "<td>"$1"</td>";
 print "<td>"$2"</td>";
 print "<td>"$3"</td>";
 print "</tr>"
  } END {
 print " </table></body></html>"
} ' $optfile | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
fi
```

**Expected Result:**

```
**Table_Name  Load Date Count**    
ABC           19/07/08  46    
DEF           19/07/06  85
```

**Actual Result:**

```
**Table_Name  Load Date Count**
ABC           19/07/08  46
ABC           19/07/08  46
DEF           19/07/06  85
```

Answer (score 1):

Your IF logic is wrong, you execute the 2nd query regardless of ACTIVITY_COUNT.

```
sel '$tbl' as tablename, cast($col as date) as Load_Date,count(*)
from $tbl where $col=cast(current_date as date format 'dd-mm-yyyy')
group by cast ($col as date);

.IF ACTIVITYCOUNT > 0 THEN .GOTO END;

sel '$tbl' as tablename, cast($col as date) as load_date, count(*) from
$tbl where cast($col as date) = current_date-1 group by load_date;

.LABEL End;
```